# Memory management when returning from function

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Suppose I have a function like this.

```
-(NSData *)getData {

  NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]init];
  return myData;
}


-(void)displayData {

    NSData *data = [self getData];

     //convert data to string

    data = [self getData];

    //Convert data to string

    data = [self getData];

    //convert data to string

    [data release];

}
```

Here I call get data three times and assign to same object but releasing only once. So does this steps leak memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write getData() as below , you need to specify autorelease in getdate() , otherwise memory leak will occur

```
-(NSData *)getData {

  NSData *myData = [[[NSData alloc]init] autorelease];
  return myData;
}


-(void)displayData 
{

    NSData *data = [[self getData] retain]; // since getdata giving you an autoreleased object 

    //before assigning new value , you have to take care of old value .
    [data release];
    data = nil;

    //convert data to string
    data = [[self getData] retain];


    [data release];
    data = nil;
   //Convert data to string

   data = [[self getData] retain];

   [data release];
   data = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It must be a non-arc project since [self release] is compiling.  If that's the case, then yes, the code you posted leaks two empty NSData instances each time displayData is called.

In an arc project, the static analysis will insert releases before each assignment avoiding the leaks.